# Repairing MP4 files?

Tags: video, repair, mp4

I have some .mp4 files. Recently they don't work anymore. No matter which players and codec packs I use, the files show as corrupt, damaged, can't render etc.

I've also tried using [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to extract information from the files but it doesn't show anything.

Is there any possible way to repair them?

**SMPlayer Log**

```
[08:53:56:569] BaseGui::fileOpen
[08:53:58:409] BaseGui::openFile: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:410] Core::openFile: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:410] Core::playNewFile: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:410] Core::saveMediaInfo
[08:53:58:410] FileSettingsHash::existSettingsFor: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:412] FileSettingsHash::existSettingsFor: config_file: 'C:/Users/Hamed/.smplayer/file_settings/0/0396255eb8d37a72.ini'
[08:53:58:412] Core::playNewFile: We have settings for this file!!!
[08:53:58:412] FileSettings::loadSettingsFor: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:415] FileSettingsHash::loadSettingsFor: config_file: 'C:/Users/Hamed/.smplayer/file_settings/0/0396255eb8d37a72.ini'
[08:53:58:416] MediaSettings::load
[08:53:58:416] Core::playNewFile: Media settings read
[08:53:58:416] Core::playNewFile: volume: 40, old_volume: 40
[08:53:58:416] Core::initPlaying
[08:53:58:416] Core::startMplayer
[08:53:58:416] Core::startMplayer: setting working directory to 'C:/Users/Hamed/.smplayer/screenshots'
[08:53:58:417] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 27667 with 30369
[08:53:58:417] Core::startMplayer: priority of smplayer process set to 128
[08:53:58:417] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 27872 with 30369
[08:53:58:418] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 24924 with 30369
[08:53:58:418] Core::startMplayer: file basename: 'C:/Users/Hamed/Desktop/1'
[08:53:58:418] Core::startMplayer: edl file: ''
[08:53:58:418] MplayerLayer::playingStarted
[08:53:58:418] Screen::playingStarted
[08:53:58:418] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 1
[08:53:58:418] Screen::playingStarted
[08:53:58:418] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 1
[08:53:58:419] Core::startMplayer: command: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/SMPlayer/mplayer/mplayer.exe -noquiet -nofs -nomouseinput -sub-fuzziness 1 -identify -slave -vo direct3d, -nokeepaspect -priority abovenormal -framedrop -nodr -double -wid 656922 -colorkey 0x020202 -monitorpixelaspect 1 -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-line-spacing 0 -ass-font-scale 1 -ass-styles C:/Users/Hamed/.smplayer/styles.ass -fontconfig -font Arial -subfont-autoscale 0 -subfont-osd-scale 20 -subfont-text-scale 20 -subcp ISO-8859-1 -subpos 100 -volume 50 -nocache -osdlevel 0 -vf-add screenshot -slices -channels 2 -af scaletempo,equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 -softvol -softvol-max 110 D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:442] Playlist::setModified: 0
[08:53:58:442] Playlist::addFiles
[08:53:58:442] Playlist::addItem: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:442] Playlist::updateView
[08:53:58:443] Playlist::updateView: name: 'v_end.mp4'
[08:53:58:443] Playlist::addFiles: latest_dir: 'C:/Users/Hamed/Desktop'
[08:53:58:529] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'MPlayer Sherpya-SVN-r30369-4.2.5 (C) 2000-2009 MPlayer Team'
[08:53:58:531] MplayerVersion::mplayerVersion: MPlayer SVN revision found: 30369
[08:53:58:531] MplayerProcess::parseLine: MPlayer SVN: 30369
[08:53:58:534] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Setting process priority: abovenormal'
[08:53:58:534] MplayerProcess::parseLine: ''
[08:53:58:534] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Playing D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4.'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Seek failed'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: ''
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: ''
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Exiting... (End of file)'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: detected end of file
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'ID_EXIT=EOF'
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: detected end of file
[08:54:00:912] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:54:00:913] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:54:00:913] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:54:00:913] MyProcess::procFinished
[08:54:00:913] MyProcess::procFinished: Bytes available: 0
[08:54:00:913] MplayerProcess::processFinished: exitCode: 0, status: 0
[08:54:00:913] MplayerLayer::playingStopped
[08:54:00:913] Screen::playingStopped
[08:54:00:913] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[08:54:00:913] Screen::playingStopped
[08:54:00:913] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[08:54:00:914] Core::finishRestart: --- start ---
[08:54:00:914] Core::newMediaPlaying: --- start ---
[08:54:00:914] Core::initializeMenus
[08:54:00:914] BaseGui::initializeMenus
[08:54:00:914] MediaData::list
[08:54:00:914]   filename: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:54:00:914]   duration: 0.000000
[08:54:00:914]   video_width: 0
[08:54:00:914]   video_height: 0
[08:54:00:914]   video_aspect: 1.333333
[08:54:00:914]   type: 0
[08:54:00:914]   novideo: 0
[08:54:00:914]   dvd_id: ''
[08:54:00:914]   initialized: 1
[08:54:00:914]   chapters: 0
[08:54:00:914]   Subs:
[08:54:00:914]   Programs:
[08:54:00:914]   Videos:
[08:54:00:914]   Audios:
[08:54:00:914]   Titles:
[08:54:00:914]   demuxer: ''
[08:54:00:914]   video_format: ''
[08:54:00:914]   audio_format: ''
[08:54:00:914]   video_bitrate: 0
[08:54:00:914]   video_fps: ''
[08:54:00:914]   audio_bitrate: 0
[08:54:00:914]   audio_rate: 0
[08:54:00:914]   audio_nch: 0
[08:54:00:914]   video_codec: ''
[08:54:00:914]   audio_codec: ''
[08:54:00:914] MediaSettings::list
[08:54:00:914]   current_sec: 0.000000
[08:54:00:914]   current_sub_id: -1000
[08:54:00:914]   current_program_id: -1000
[08:54:00:914]   current_video_id: -1000
[08:54:00:914]   current_audio_id: -1000
[08:54:00:914]   current_title_id: -1000
[08:54:00:915]   current_chapter_id: 0
[08:54:00:915]   current_angle_id: -1000
[08:54:00:915]   aspect_ratio_id: 1
[08:54:00:915]   volume: 40
[08:54:00:915]   mute: 0
[08:54:00:915]   external_subtitles: ''
[08:54:00:915]   external_audio: ''
[08:54:00:915]   sub_delay: 0
[08:54:00:915]   audio_delay: 0
[08:54:00:915]   sub_pos: 100
[08:54:00:915]   sub_scale: 5.000000
[08:54:00:915]   sub_scale_ass: 1.000000
[08:54:00:915]   brightness: 0
[08:54:00:915]   contrast: 0
[08:54:00:915]   gamma: 0
[08:54:00:915]   hue: 0
[08:54:00:915]   saturation: 0
[08:54:00:915]   speed: 1.000000
[08:54:00:915]   phase_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   current_denoiser: 0
[08:54:00:915]   deblock_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   dering_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   noise_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   postprocessing_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   upscaling_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   current_deinterlacer: 0
[08:54:00:915]   add_letterbox: 0
[08:54:00:915]   karaoke_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   extrastereo_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   volnorm_filter: 0
[08:54:00:915]   audio_use_channels: 2
[08:54:00:915]   stereo_mode: 0
[08:54:00:915]   zoom_factor: 1.000000
[08:54:00:915]   rotate: -1
[08:54:00:915]   flip: 0
[08:54:00:915]   mirror: 0
[08:54:00:915]   loop: 0
[08:54:00:915]   A_marker: -1
[08:54:00:915]   B_marker: -1
[08:54:00:915]   forced_demuxer: ''
[08:54:00:915]   forced_video_codec: ''
[08:54:00:915]   forced_audio_codec: ''
[08:54:00:915]   original_demuxer: ''
[08:54:00:915]   original_video_codec: ''
[08:54:00:915]   original_audio_codec: ''
[08:54:00:915]   mplayer_additional_options: ''
[08:54:00:915]   mplayer_additional_video_filters: ''
[08:54:00:915]   mplayer_additional_audio_filters: ''
[08:54:00:915]   win_width: 400
[08:54:00:915]   win_height: 300
[08:54:00:916]   win_aspect(): 1.333333
[08:54:00:916]   starting_time: -1.000000
[08:54:00:916]   is264andHD: 0
[08:54:00:916] Core::newMediaPlaying: --- end ---
[08:54:00:916] BaseGui::enterFullscreenOnPlay: arg_start_in_fullscreen: -1, pref->start_in_fullscreen: 0
[08:54:00:916] Core::changeAspectRatio: 1
[08:54:00:916] Core::displayMessage
[08:54:00:916] Core::setVolume: 50
[08:54:00:916] Core::tellmp: 'volume 50 1'
[08:54:00:916] WARNING:  tellmp: no process running: volume 50 1
[08:54:00:916] Core::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:916] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:916] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:916] Core::displayMessage
[08:54:00:917] Core::changeZoom: 1.000000
[08:54:00:917] Core::displayMessage
[08:54:00:918] Core::changeSubVisilibity: 1
[08:54:00:918] Core::tellmp: 'sub_visibility 1'
[08:54:00:918] WARNING:  tellmp: no process running: sub_visibility 1
[08:54:00:918] Core::displayMessage
[08:54:00:918] DefaultGui::enableActionsOnPlaying
[08:54:00:918] BaseGui::enableActionsOnPlaying
[08:54:00:920] BaseGui::autosaveMplayerLog
[08:54:00:920] Playlist:: getMediaInfo
[08:54:00:920] Playlist::updateView
[08:54:00:920] Playlist::updateView: name: 'v_end.mp4'
[08:54:00:920] BaseGuiPlus::updateMediaInfo
[08:54:00:920] BaseGui::updateMediaInfo
[08:54:00:921] Core::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:921] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:921] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:921] Core::finishRestart: --- end ---
[08:54:00:921] Core::processFinished
[08:54:00:921] Core::processFinished: we_are_restarting: 0
[08:54:00:921] Core::processFinished: play has finished!
[08:54:00:921] Core::processFinished: exit_code: 0
[08:54:00:921] Core::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:921] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:921] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[08:54:00:921] DefaultGui::disableActionsOnStop
[08:54:00:921] BaseGui::disableActionsOnStop
[08:54:00:922] BaseGui::newMediaLoaded
[08:54:00:922] Recents::addItem: 'D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:54:00:922] BaseGui::updateRecents
[08:54:00:922] BaseGui::checkPendingActionsToRun
[08:54:00:922] Core::checkIfVideoIsHD
[08:54:00:923] Playlist::playNext
[08:54:00:923] Playlist::updateView
[08:54:00:923] Playlist::updateView: name: 'v_end.mp4'
[08:54:00:923] Playlist::playItem: 1 (count:1)
[08:54:00:923] Playlist::playItem: out of range
[08:54:00:923] BaseGui::playlistHasFinished
[08:54:00:923] BaseGui::playlistHasFinished: arg_close_on_finish: -1, pref->close_on_finish: 0
[08:54:03:127] Core::changeOSD: 1
[08:54:03:127] Core::pausing_prefix
[08:54:03:127] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 27665 with 30369
[08:54:03:127] Core::tellmp: 'pausing_keep_force osd 1'
[08:54:03:127] WARNING:  tellmp: no process running: pausing_keep_force osd 1
[08:54:03:127] Core::updateWidgets
[08:54:03:127] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[08:54:03:127] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[08:55:28:446] MplayerWindow::mouseReleaseEvent
[08:55:28:446] BaseGui::leftClickFunction
[08:55:28:446] BaseGui::processFunction: 'dvdnav_mouse'
[08:55:28:446] BaseGui::processFunction: action found
[08:55:28:446] Core::dvdnavMouse
[08:55:33:987] Core::play
[08:55:33:987] Core::initPlaying
[08:55:33:987] Core::startMplayer
[08:55:33:988] Core::startMplayer: setting working directory to 'C:/Users/Hamed/.smplayer/screenshots'
[08:55:33:988] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 27667 with 30369
[08:55:33:988] Core::startMplayer: priority of smplayer process set to 128
[08:55:33:989] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 27872 with 30369
[08:55:33:989] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 24924 with 30369
[08:55:33:989] Core::startMplayer: file basename: 'C:/Users/Hamed/Desktop/1'
[08:55:33:989] Core::startMplayer: edl file: ''
[08:55:33:989] MplayerLayer::playingStarted
[08:55:33:990] Screen::playingStarted
[08:55:33:990] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 1
[08:55:33:990] Screen::playingStarted
[08:55:33:990] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 1
[08:55:33:990] Core::startMplayer: command: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/SMPlayer/mplayer/mplayer.exe -noquiet -nofs -nomouseinput -sub-fuzziness 1 -identify -slave -vo direct3d, -nokeepaspect -priority abovenormal -framedrop -nodr -double -wid 656922 -colorkey 0x020202 -monitorpixelaspect 1 -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-line-spacing 0 -ass-font-scale 1 -ass-styles C:/Users/Hamed/.smplayer/styles.ass -fontconfig -font Arial -subfont-autoscale 0 -subfont-osd-scale 20 -subfont-text-scale 20 -subcp ISO-8859-1 -subpos 100 -volume 50 -nocache -osdlevel 0 -vf-add screenshot -slices -channels 2 -af scaletempo,equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 -softvol -softvol-max 110 D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4'
[08:55:34:103] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'MPlayer Sherpya-SVN-r30369-4.2.5 (C) 2000-2009 MPlayer Team'
[08:55:34:103] MplayerVersion::mplayerVersion: MPlayer SVN revision found: 30369
[08:55:34:103] MplayerProcess::parseLine: MPlayer SVN: 30369
[08:55:34:103] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Setting process priority: abovenormal'
[08:55:34:103] MplayerProcess::parseLine: ''
[08:55:34:103] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Playing D:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4.'
[08:55:36:398] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:55:36:398] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:55:36:398] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:55:36:398] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:55:36:398] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Seek failed'
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: ''
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: ''
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'Exiting... (End of file)'
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: detected end of file
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'ID_EXIT=EOF'
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: detected end of file
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::parseLine: 'iconv: conversion from UTF-8 to CP720 unsupported'
[08:55:36:457] MyProcess::procFinished
[08:55:36:457] MyProcess::procFinished: Bytes available: 0
[08:55:36:457] MplayerProcess::processFinished: exitCode: 0, status: 0
[08:55:36:457] MplayerLayer::playingStopped
[08:55:36:458] Screen::playingStopped
[08:55:36:458] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[08:55:36:458] Screen::playingStopped
[08:55:36:458] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[08:55:36:458] Core::finishRestart: --- start ---
[08:55:36:458] Core::changeAspectRatio: 1
[08:55:36:458] Core::displayMessage
[08:55:36:458] Core::setVolume: 50
[08:55:36:458] Core::tellmp: 'volume 50 1'
[08:55:36:458] WARNING:  tellmp: no process running: volume 50 1
[08:55:36:458] Core::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:458] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:458] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:459] Core::displayMessage
[08:55:36:459] Core::changeZoom: 1.000000
[08:55:36:459] Core::displayMessage
[08:55:36:460] Core::changeSubVisilibity: 1
[08:55:36:460] Core::tellmp: 'sub_visibility 1'
[08:55:36:460] WARNING:  tellmp: no process running: sub_visibility 1
[08:55:36:460] Core::displayMessage
[08:55:36:460] DefaultGui::enableActionsOnPlaying
[08:55:36:460] BaseGui::enableActionsOnPlaying
[08:55:36:461] BaseGui::autosaveMplayerLog
[08:55:36:461] Playlist:: getMediaInfo
[08:55:36:461] Playlist::updateView
[08:55:36:461] Playlist::updateView: name: 'v_end.mp4'
[08:55:36:462] BaseGuiPlus::updateMediaInfo
[08:55:36:462] BaseGui::updateMediaInfo
[08:55:36:462] Core::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:462] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:462] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:462] Core::finishRestart: --- end ---
[08:55:36:462] Core::processFinished
[08:55:36:462] Core::processFinished: we_are_restarting: 0
[08:55:36:462] Core::processFinished: play has finished!
[08:55:36:462] Core::processFinished: exit_code: 0
[08:55:36:462] Core::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:462] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:462] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[08:55:36:462] DefaultGui::disableActionsOnStop
[08:55:36:462] BaseGui::disableActionsOnStop
[08:55:36:463] Core::checkIfVideoIsHD
[08:55:36:463] Playlist::playNext
[08:55:36:463] Playlist::updateView
[08:55:36:463] Playlist::updateView: name: 'v_end.mp4'
[08:55:36:463] Playlist::playItem: 1 (count:1)
[08:55:36:464] Playlist::playItem: out of range
[08:55:36:464] BaseGui::playlistHasFinished
[08:55:36:464] BaseGui::playlistHasFinished: arg_close_on_finish: -1, pref->close_on_finish: 0
[08:55:38:655] Core::changeOSD: 1
[08:55:38:655] Core::pausing_prefix
[08:55:38:655] MplayerVersion::isMplayerAtLeast: comparing 27665 with 30369
[08:55:38:655] Core::tellmp: 'pausing_keep_force osd 1'
[08:55:38:655] WARNING:  tellmp: no process running: pausing_keep_force osd 1
```

Comment: Why don't they work anymore, all of a sudden? Files don't really "go bad" for no reason. What exactly does MediaInfo Tools show? Maybe try [Video Repair Tool](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Video_Repair_Tool)

Comment: @slhck yes it's strange , i think it's cause of some hdd failure which i recently experienced , MediaInfo shows only name and size of movie nothing more :/ , YES i tried [Video Repair](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Video_Repair_Tool) Tools but movdump.exe gives an error "Not Responding" then it's giving a 0 byte file as repaired

Comment: @Synxmax Size, like in Bytes or length? Name, like the filename or some title embedded into the movie?

Comment: @slhck mediainfo give me this  `Complete name : d:\Summer_2010\v_end.mp4
File size : 128 MiB`

Comment: Hmm, I guess now you really have a problem. If the tools aren't able to find anything, your file probably has some major errors.

Comment: Seemingly mencoder is treating the files as zero-length. I doubt they are recoverable, if this is what all of them show. I'd suggest a good hard drive repair tool as your only remaining hope.

Answer (score 1):

Will the files play on another PC? If not, your hard drive crash damaged them, and they may well be unfixable.  One thing I've done in the past is use [mencoder](http://mplayerhq.hu) or a similar package to convert the damaged file to AVI. This at least recovers the undamaged portion.

Comment: No use :( , I added SMPlayer Log

Comment: *What* was no use? Did you try playing on another PC or using mencoder?

Comment: ye i tried different PCs , i followed that link and there is a player named smPlayer i added log of smPlayer to my question !

Comment: Right, but I recommended mencoder ... however, as I said in my comment on your question, I think you will need to find those videos again. Unless disk recovery tools work for you, they're gone forever.

Comment: Use mencoder how?